# Tagging a Docker image with Version in Gitlab with yaml

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm currently digging in Gitlab CI.
I would like to add a way in my YAML files to tag my docker images generated by the build step and pushed to my Gitlab Registry with a Version number composed in the following fashion : MajorVersion.Minorversion.BuildNumber

I would like to auto-increment the BuildNumber, but to manually set the MajorVersion and MinorVersion.

I found a standard variable **CI_JOB_ID** for the build ID. But i need a smooth way to manage my version numbers..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a 100% solutions for you but we are using TAGs for this purpose.

**Part of `gitlab-ci.yml`**

```
 - docker build --pull -t $CI_REGISTRY/releases/application:$CI_COMMIT_TAG .
 - docker push $CI_REGISTRY/releases/application:$CI_COMMIT_TAG
```

So every time we push a new tag, a new docker image with release number is build. You can limit those steps in `.gitlab-ci.yml` via:

```
  only:
    - tags
    - /^my-release-.*$/
```

Now only tags with "my-release-x.x.x" are pushed.

Comment: If I create a branch that will match this pattern, will it be deployed as well? Can I specify only tags and only those that match given pattern?

Comment: I tested this rule and if I create any tag the job is triggered, regardless of its name.

Comment: To fix the `only` condition to really only pay attention to tags do:

`only:      variables:      - $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^my-release-.*$/`

Answer (score 6):

So i did it by adding a **CI_VERSION** variable in my script :

```
variables:
  CI_VERSION: "1.0.${CI_JOB_ID}"

build-master:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE" -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_VERSION"   ./postfix
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE"
  only:
    - master
```

And it works fine, now i need to find a way to keep the ten (for example) last build.

Comment: what image are you using that has docker installed by default?